# $\int_{C(i,2)}^{}\frac{1}{(z^2+4)^2}\: dz $ (verification)

Tags: integration, solution-verification, complex-integration

I want to calculate $I=\int_{C(i,2)}^{}\frac{1}{(z^2+4)^2}\: dz$

if the denominator wasn't squared it would be easy, break the integral in 2 sums then consider 2 circles... ect

Now I am not so sure, I thought maybe doing somewhat the same would work.

$I=\int_{C(i,2)}\left [ \frac{i}{4(z+2i)}-\frac{i}{4(z-2i)} \right ]^2\: dz=\int_{C(i,2)} \frac{-1}{16(z+2i)^2}+\frac{1}{8(z-2i)(z+2i)} +\frac{-1}{16(z-2i)^2} \: dz$

I have calculated the middle one using the above method, but for the other 2 can i use Cauchy formula for $f(z)=-1/16$ ? And say they are equal to zero?

Comment: Have you tried/know the residue theorem? $\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz = 2\pi i \sum_{j=1}^{k}Res(f,a_j)Ind_{\gamma}(a_j)$ where Ind is the winding number?

Comment: Your approach seems fine to me, but I'm no complex-analysis expert. I just finished my course on it 1 week ago.

Comment: Does $C(i,2)$ mean the circle centered at $z=i$ with radius $2$?

Comment: i am familiar with the winding number but not that formula, not yet at least.

Comment: @user170231 yes you are correct i thought it was standard way to write it so i didn't explain it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is almost correct except for one minor detail.

• $z=-2i$ lies **outside** $C$, so the first integral contributes nothing (due to [Cauchy's integral *theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem)). The integral formula does not apply.

• For the second integral, you can use the formula with $f(z)=\frac1{8(z+2i)}$:

$$\oint_C\frac{\mathrm dz}{8(z+2i)(z-2i)}=2\pi i\cdot\frac1{8(z+2i)}\bigg|_{z=2i}=\frac\pi{16}$$

• For the third integral, use [Cauchy's differentiation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem), indeed with $f(z)=-\frac1{16}$:

$$-\oint_C\frac{\mathrm dz}{16(z-2i)^2}=2\pi i\cdot\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dz}\left[-\frac1{16}\right]\right)\bigg|_{z=2i}=0$$

Then $I=\dfrac\pi{16}$.

---

You get the same result using the residue theorem:

$$I=2\pi i\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac1{(z^2+4)^2},z=2i\right)=2\pi i\lim_{z\to2i}\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dz}\left[\frac{(z-2i)^2}{(z^2+4)^2}\right]=2\pi i\cdot\left(-\frac i{32}\right)=\frac\pi{16}$$